# Bootstrap Modal with foreach loop. How can pass the foreach argument?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm working with PHP (Laravel 5.3) and developing a Blade view with a Bootstrap modal that have a foreach loop inside to show too many rows. This modal is called from a table that, in the end of every row have a button for more details (and this details are an array).

So, how can I pass the array data to the modal?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered m-table" id="business">
        <thead class="columns">     
            <tr>
                <th class="column1">Name</th>
                <th class="column2">Contact</th>
                <th class="column3">Details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="main-rows list" >
            @foreach ($listBusiness as $business)
                <tr>                                                        
                    <td class="column1">{{$business->name}}</td>
                    <td class="column2">{{$business->contact}}</td>
                    <td class="column7">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBusinessDetails">
                            <i class="la la-search"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>                           
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Modal table -->
<div class="modal" id="modalBusinessDetails" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <div class="col-12">                                
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered m-table" id="business">
                            <thead class="columns">     
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="column1">Created at</th>
                                    <th class="column2">Active</th>
                                    <th class="column2">Employees</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="main-rows">
                                @foreach ($ListDetail as $BusinessDetail)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="column1">{{$BusinessDetail->created_at}}</td>
                                        <td class="column2">{{$BusinessDetail->active}}</td>
                                        <td class="column3 text-center">{{$BusinessDetail->employees}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn group">
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">{{Tr('Close')}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you will need to use javascript to change the contents of the modal

Comment: or, make multiple modals (not recommended)

Comment: that is why there is AJAX, on your button put some id in a function and after clicking that button you can make AJAX call to retrieve more data from DB

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Vidal said, this requires JS (the likes of AJAX, AXIOS, etc)
Here is my sample controller method that you can use for something like that.

```
function getData(Request $request)
{
   $data = DB::table('table_name')->get(); //can be done differently
   //create separate view for dynamic data e.g table <tbody>AJAX or AXIOS response</tbody>
   $returnHTML = view('view_name',compact('data'))->render();

   return response()->json( ['success' => true, 'html' => $returnHTML] );

}
```

Hope it helps.